# Merging 2 or more lists with addition of integers

Tags: python

I am writing a code for a cart (sort of) i am having a problem where when user purchase an item twice it should add its quantity and price automatically.

What my file contains:

```
Apple 300 2 kg
Shirt Medium Blue 1350 3 shirt
Shirt Medium Blue 1850 4 shirt
```

I want this Shirt Medium Blue to merge.
What i am trying so far

```
l = -1
lol = []


for line in lines:
    l += 1
    shirt = (line.rsplit(" ", 3))
    lol.append(shirt)
    if shirts[l][0] in shirt:
        print('found')
```

How can i make the program to check the line and add its index [1] which is price and [2] quantity

Answer (score -1):

```
s = """Apple 300 2 kg
Shirt Medium Blue 1350 3 shirt
Shirt Medium Blue 1850 4 shirt"""

from collections import Counter
import re

m = re.findall('([^\d]+)(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)', s)
c_price = Counter()
c_items = Counter()
for g in m:
    c_price.update( {(g[0].strip(), g[3]): int(g[1])}  )
    c_items.update( {(g[0].strip(), g[3]): int(g[2])}  )

for (item_name, item_type), count in c_items.items():
    print(item_name, c_price[(item_name, item_type)], count, item_type)
```

Outputs:

```
Apple 300 2 kg
Shirt Medium Blue 3200 7 shirt
```